# Wrong sort order(JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

How to sort topics by the date of the last post "last_post_time" in "table #__kunena_topics" ?

```
    $query ='SELECT cat.name as cat_name,
  cat.id as cat_id,
  top.id as top_id,
  top.subject as top_subject
FROM #__kunena_topics top
JOIN #__kunena_categories cat ON cat.id = top.category_id
WHERE cat.parent_id = '.$secid.' and cat.locked = 0 and top.locked = 0
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM #__kunena_topics
  WHERE top.category_id = category_id
  AND top.id <= id
) <= 3';
```

I tried, but it does not work:

```
 ..........
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM #__kunena_topics
  WHERE top.category_id = category_id
  AND top.id <= id
) <= 3 ORDER BY top.last_post_time DESC';
```

result

```
foreach ($this->items as $i => $object) : 
?>
    <?php   if($object->cat_id != $lastcategory) { ?>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;border-bottom:3px solid black;">
    <?php echo "category:". $object->cat_id; ?>
    </div>
    <?php  } ?>
    <div style="margin-top: 1px;border-bottom:1px solid black;"> <?php
     echo "topic:". $object->top_subject;
      $lastcategory = $object->cat_id;
      ?>
      </div> <?php
                endforeach; ?>
```

Now displays

```
"CATEGORY 1"; "topic 3"; "topic 4"; "topic 5"; "CATEGORY 2"; "topic 55"; "topic 56"; "topic 57";
```

and I want it

```
"CATEGORY 1"; "topic 5"; "topic 4"; "topic 3"; "CATEGORY 2"; "topic 57"; "topic 56"; "topic 55";
```

table: `#__kunena_topics`:

[image: tabel: #__kunena_topics]

result:

[image: result]

Comment: why you use count(*) in query ?

Comment: what exact output you want , please post here.

Comment: display the child categories of a specific parent category (parent_id in #__kunena_categories) and  select the last 3 topics (order by last_post_time in #__kunena_topics ) from each child category.

Now displays
"CATEGORY 1";
"topic 3";
"topic 4";
"topic 5";

"CATEGORY 2";
"topic 55";
"topic 56";
"topic 57";

and I want it
"CATEGORY 1";
"topic 5";
"topic 4";
"topic 3";

"CATEGORY 2";
"topic 57";
"topic 56";
"topic 55";

Comment: You can [edit] your question and include additional info there